# Href passing page options

Tags: javascript, django, python-2.7, django-views

My current URL is something like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/browse/?name=&status=any
```

On it I have a paginator which allows me to browse by page number. How would I set the href so it goes to the next page, while passing in the `name` and `status` options? So for example the href for `page2` should be:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/browse/?name=&status=any&page=2
```

But if I set

```
<a href="?page={{ paginator.previous_page_number }}">
```

Then the URL is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/browse/?page=2
```

Does anyone know how I can get this done?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you for got the rest. So..

in:

```
<a href="?page={{ paginator.previous_page_number }}">
```

should be

```
<a href="?name=&status=any&page={{ paginator.previous_page_number }}">
```

Right? I think? Reason is because the paginator part only provides the page number. So you need the rest to go with it.

Comment: Yes, but the URL can change, for example the page can be:

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/browse/?name=Testing&status=any&page=2`, or `http://127.0.0.1:8000/browse/?name=&status=Run&page=2`, etc. So the search fields are dynamic :(